# How was the 80186 incompatible with the IBM PC?

Tags: history, hardware, ibm-pc, 80186

Wikipedia's [Intel 80186](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80186) entrymentions

> The 80186 would have been a natural successor to the 8086 in personal computers. However, because its integrated hardware was incompatible with the hardware used in the original IBM PC, the 80286 was used as the successor instead in the IBM PC/AT.

That explains why most of the PC compatibles didn't use it either.

What exactly did the 186 do that was incompatible with the IBM PC?

Comment: Yeah weird - "completely object code compatible with the 8086" - http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/80186/index.html

Comment: I see it was used in the RM Nimbus. Used those things in college. Infuriatingly almost-but-not-quite-IBM-compatible.

Comment: This has been asked before, in a way: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/why-is-the-rm-nimbus-pc-186-not-ibm-pc-compatible/5107 As I understand it, the 80186 integrates timers, an interrupt controller and a DMA controller, which are incompatible with the external components used in the IBM PC.

Comment: Has been asked before: please see my answer https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5111/5199

Comment: I had an 80186 Co-processor unit (for the BBC Micro) - had 512k of RAM on the board.
It ran a version of DOS that was pretty close (similar to 3.1, IIRC) and could play games that didn't try to use any direct hardware addressing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The main issue with the 80186 isn’t with the CPU core itself, but with its integrated peripherals: they aren’t compatible with those used in the IBM PC, and they aren’t integrated in the same way either.

The IBM PC uses an 8237 DMA controller at offset 0x00 in the I/O address space, an 8259 [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interrupt_controller) at offset 0x20, and an 8253 [PIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interval_timer) at offset 0x40. The 80186’s integrated peripherals are mapped using a “peripheral control block”, which can be moved around in the I/O address space (it defaults to 0xFF00), but their offsets are fixed and don’t match the PC’s: while the PIC is at offset 0x20, the PIT is at offset 0x50, and the DMA descriptors are at offset 0xC0. The DMA control registers aren’t the same as the 8237’s, so code expecting an 8237 won’t work with the 80186. The 80186’s PIC and PIT are more sophisticated than the 8253 and 8259, and controlled rather differently too.

The 80186 also has more reserved hardware interrupts than the 8086.

A number of more-or-less compatible computers were made using the 80186, including one which has already been discussed here ([Why is the RM Nimbus PC-186 not IBM PC compatible?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5099/79)), and famously, the [Tandy 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandy_2000), [Siemens PC-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_PC-D), and a few of HP’s line of palmtop PCs (100LX, 200LX, 1000CX). These were at most DOS- and Windows-compatible, thanks to DOS’ and Windows’ ability to run on non-PC-compatible systems (with appropriate hardware interface layers). Many such computers took advantage of their non-PC-compatibility to provide improvements compared to the PC, *e.g.* [more memory for DOS programs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7818/79).

Comment: There was also the Swedish COMPIS, running CP/M from ROM (by default), designed as a computer for schools. Famously has a LOT of different IO connectors on the back side, but (IIRC) no RS-232.

Comment: I have vague memories of the 80186--sort of a precursor to today's highly integrated, single-chip microcontrollers, wasn't it? Pretty sure I sat in the same room with somebody who was developing some kind of embedded system that had an 80186 in it once, long ago.

Comment: @Solomon yes, it’s an SoC, targeted at embedded systems (my Intel manual for the 80186 is part of the “embedded microprocessors” series, along with the 386-based 376).

Comment: Couldn't one, in theory, map the 186's internal devices to a non-colliding offset, ignore these devices and use an external PIC, PIT, and DMA controller?

Comment: @JCCyC perhaps (and at least the 80186’s internal PIC can work with external 8259s), but then you’d be spending extra for hardware you don’t want (the integrated peripherals), extra on board design and firmware, all for not much benefit — the 80186 was better than the 8086 but not enough to warrant all that effort. The 80286 was contemporaneous, so I think most designers would have targeted that instead if they wanted more than an 8086...

Comment: Of course, from the perspective of typical Dos software the incompatibilities were irrelevant. Anything that used only DOS or BIOS interrupts to interface with the hardware could be made to run. As a user of a Nimbus PC186, for example, the most relevant issue was that the graphics interface of those machines wasn't completely compatible with any standard PC display (it could be set into a CGA compatibility mode but only with a fixed pallette, iirc, so a lot of programs ended up with odd looking colours).

Comment: yes, 80186 was used a lot in embedded stuff thanks to its intergrated peripherals and decode logic. It had programmable chips select logic which allowed to define several memory ROM and RAM regions. This spared a lot of glue logic. A lot of variants with more feature were developped during the years by Intel (186EC with 4 high speed serial channels) and AMD (Am186EM) Some variants were used up until the year 2000. 
My company used AM186EM which was really nice, demultiplexed bus, up to 40 MHz, a lot of I/O, serial ports etc.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter I recently build a small system using a 50 MHz AM186ER. Got an integer performance making all 286 systems eating dust, on par with a 20 MHz 80386. And it'S mid range selects can be nicely tweeked to emulate a LIM-EMS Card.

Comment: @Raffzahn the mid range selects were already on the regular 186. Very nice, I had also built an extended memory scheme for our terminal controller that could handle up to 4 MiB, by using 4 16KiB windows in segment D000 (we had 128KiB ROM and the rest was RAM). It emulated an access scheme defined by Siemens in one of theit terminal.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter I know, and D000h _is_ the standard LIM window. What Terminal If I may ask?

Comment: Controller for Siemens ES-1 and ES-2 access terminals (PZE und BDE Terminals). The Siemens controller was the ES-122C and our low-cost were the EC-115 and EC-270.
As for the LIM window, if my scheme was compatible it would have been completely incidental as it was absolutely not supposed to be.

Comment: Here the only pic I found of a terminal from the ES-3 series (which was still branded siemens but were sold by a successor company).
https://www.ebay.fr/itm/163915056029
The ES-3 series is interesting in that they use the Am186EM and don't need the big central controllers listed above. They also had ethernet with TCP/IP long before the concurrent products (ca.1994).

Comment: As regards 80186-based computers, don't forget the Goupil G4, which was notable not only for using the 80186 but also [for running multitasking MS-DOS 4](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/multitasking-ms-dos-4-0-goupil-oem/).

Answer (score 8):

Stephens Answer points out most details, I belive it's worth to mention that the 80186 is not incompatible with the IBM-PC's structure/hardware per se. The CPU core works for all details like a 286 in real mode, with the same additional instructions and exceptions, as there are:

Instructions:

- Array Check (BOUND)
- Integer Multiplication Immediate 8/16 (IMUL)
- Push Immediate 8/16
- Push/Pop All (PUSHA/POPA)
- Shift Instructions with Immediate Count (ROL/RCL/SHL/etc.)
- Multi Byte/Word Input (INSB/W)
- Multi Byte/Word Output (OUTB/W)
- Stack Frame Handling (ENTER/LEAVE)

Exceptions:

- INT 5 Array Check
- INT 6 Unused Instruction
- INT 7 ESC Instruction (FPU)

So far software will run into the same incompatibilities as with an 286.

Further it's incompatible additional hardware aren't as much of an issue, depending on the design choosen.

As Stephen said, the included peripherals are superior to IBM's choice of 8 bit components. This is especially true for the DMA controller, able to transfer to any location at any length (up to 64 KiB).

While the address structure of the I/O block is complete different from the PC, it doesn't get in the way of any PC hardware as it it located at FF00h after reset. An area no PC-hardware (I know) occupies. Not even later one. It can be moved to any location in IO *or* memory address space.

The most obvious way to reach IBM-PC compatibility would adding everything exactly s the PC did. While this would eliminate many of the advantages of having integrated peripherals, but that sounds worse as it is, as most of a PC-I/O could be added as a single southbridge chip.

The only remaining incompatibility would be the Interrupt Controller (PIC), as it's located on a different address.

This is where the quite handy address decoder could be used. By connecting it's output to NMI and setting it to cover the I/O address range 0000h..03FFh, which is the range all I/O in the original PC was located, it would generate an NMI (*1) with each access (*2). Now an NMI handler can decode the offending instruction (*3) and translate it to the real hardware and back.

With 80186 systems running at least at 6 MHz or above, the translation layer's performance impact was tolerable. In fact, I do only remember one usage which could not be emulated, and that's active sound generation, that's were the CPU essentially handles the speaker in software. something already critical on genuine hardware.

The [Olivetti Prodest PC1](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_Prodest_PC_1) of 1987 (!), based on a [NEC V40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEC_V20#Variants_and_successors) (a SoC much like an 80188, but with PC like timer/UART/PIO) did for use an NMI handler to emulate a PC compatible 8237 DMA controller while using the build in 20 bit DMA.

Long story short: It's quite possible to use an 80186 and its advantages while being mostly compatible.

---

The mentioned PC-D, being conceived as Unix workstation, did offer a different way. Here all memory and I/O was required to handle the READY signal, controlled by a watchdog timer provided by the 80186 as well. While this in theory could be used for emulation as well (I did so), the performance impact was rather heavy, as it only fired after about 1 millisecond. Eons in CPU time. The nice part was that the system ROM, [much like MS-Windows](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11869/6659), routed any NMI by default into the ROM based debugger. From there it was just a few commands until one could patch the offending software to run flawless :)

---

*1 - NMI is a strange fellow on the IBM-PC AT, anyway, as it could be masked. Jep, that's something one needs to read twice, as the very feature of an NMI is to be not maskable, so it can be used to report critical conditions (like memory error).

*2 - The same can be archived by simply selecting all I/O with top 6 bits zero, which needs a single TTL, leaving the PCS signals to other use.

*3 - While decoding an offending memory instruction, with just the address of the *next* instruction, as the NMI provides, is an quite complicated and rather error prone process, it's straight forward when it comes to I/O, as there are only 4 (well, 8 with INS/OUTS) opcodes to detect, and they have fixed formats.

To only possible ambiguity would be direct address (8 bit port number) instructions, but luckily That address range (0Exh) is unused on the PC. Similar the INS/OUTS do not collide either - well, they aren't to be expected with 8088 software at all.

Answer (score 1):

Working from memory and in addition to what everybody else has said, the order of the memory access and SP increment/decrement in the push and pop opcodes changed relative to the 8086 and 8088.

This was the standard way of checking whether a CPU was an 88/86 or a 188/186. You could distinguish between the 88/188 and 86/186 by using self-modifying code to explore the length of the prefetch queue, and some related technique allowed the V20/30 to be identified.

I forget for the moment how the code that distinguished between a 188/186 and a 286 worked, and from the '386 onwards there was a CPUID opcode.

Comment: `CPUID` was only added in the Intel Pentium, and retro-fitted to the last 486s. Detecting a 386 or a 486 involved checking for new flags in the flags register. In the checks I’m aware of (and used back in the day), the `PUSH SP` difference was used to distinguish between <286 and 286, not 808x and 18x; the latter were distinguished using the `SHL` behaviour (truncating `CL` to five bits). Put another way, `PUSH SP` behaves the same on 808x and 18x, `SHL` behaves the same on 18x and 286.

Comment: But none of this makes the 80186 incompatible with the IBM PC: the 286 behaved in the same way, and wasn’t incompatible with the IBM PC.